# Magento - Change Password confirmation E-Mail

Tags: php, email, magento, hyperlink, confirmation

Hi is there a way to get an E-Mail when my password has been changed? The normal workaround in magento is, that you get a link to change the password, then you can change it, but you do not get a confirmation, that your password has been changed.

Greetings,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Use an observer to listen for the event `customer_save_before`.

To detect password change and send mail, use following code within the observer:

```
$_customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$_post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

if($_customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer && !$_customer->isObjectNew()) {
    if( $_post['change_password'] == 1) {
        // Code to send email
    }
}
```

Comment: IThis sounds good. I will habe to check how to implementiert an observer. Thank you very much for for your advice and help.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct answer for others with same question.